# When trying to debug locally the app runs but when debuging remotly it crashes - Output msg: 0xe0434352

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging, windows-rt

Ok, I have an app here which runs perfectly if I debug it on the Local Machine. However, when I try to run it remotly on a tablet with Windows RT, it starts to run and then crashes giving me the following output message:

Loaded '..\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[5800] FieldService.WinRT.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).

I'm working with VS 2012 and running as administrator.

I've been trying to fix this issue during all the day, and found some possible solutions that did not help. So I'd appreciate any suggestion. :)